# comparing 2 squences in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have 2 sequences one is from 1 to 10 and other is 1 to 3.
how to compare the second sequence with first sequence to test whether first 3 items are same ?

Comment: Can you show use the XML, as it isn't clear whether the sequence is a list of elements, or just a text element with a comma-delimited list in. Also, showing you expected results and any XSLT you have done so far would also help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Use this short XPath expression**:

```
deep-equal(subsequence($seq1, 1, count($seq2)), $seq2)
```

When evaluated it produces `true()` exactly if the second sequence is a starting subsequence of the first. The two sequences can contain a mixture of any XDM items, including nodes.

**Here is a full demonstration**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vSeq1" select=
        "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vSeq2" select=
        "1, 2, 3"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vSeq3" select="/*/*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vSeq4" select="/*/*[position() gt 5]"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vSeq5" select="/*/*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vSeq6" select="/*/*[position() le 5]"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select=
     "deep-equal(subsequence($vSeq1, 1, count($vSeq2)), $vSeq2)"/>
     ===========
     <xsl:sequence select=
     "deep-equal(subsequence($vSeq3, 1, count($vSeq4)), $vSeq4)"/>
     ===========
     <xsl:sequence select=
     "deep-equal(subsequence($vSeq5, 1, count($vSeq6)), $vSeq6)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
 true
 ===========
 false
 ===========
 true
```

Comment: @XSLT_FRESHER: I am glad this answer was useful to you. Why not *accept* it (by clicking on the check-mark next to the best answer)? :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two variables `seq1` and `seq2` you can simply test `<xsl:if test="$seq1[1] eq $seq2[1] and $seq1[2] eq $seq2[2] and $seq1[3] eq $seq2[3]">...</xsl:if>`.